# Does a higher switching frequency in SiC MOSFET mean higher efficiency?

Tags: mosfet, frequency, efficiency, sic

https://www.we-online.com/en/news-center/blog?d=design-drivers-sic-mosfets

From this link, it says "The SiC MOSFET's extremely fast switching speed helps to achieve higher efficiency".

Is this true? How do you justify this statement?

Comment: Do you know what is usually the biggest component in a switching converter (when components are compared physically)? Do you know why it's the biggest? Do you know that at low frequencies this component gets very large and costly? Are you currently sitting an exam? Is this homework?

Comment: This is for a project. I believe for a switching converter, (in our case, flyback converter), the coupled inductor or maybe the switch could be the largest. but not so sure.

Comment: It reduces switching losses for a given frequency, but increased _switching frequency_ brings higher switching losses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *From this link, it says "The SiC MOSFET's extremely fast switching
> speed helps to achieve higher efficiency". Is this true? How do you
> justify this statement?*

If you operate a switching converter at low frequencies, the inductor/transformer gets big and costly. This is why we use high frequencies typically 100 kHz. At these frequencies the "wound" component becomes a fraction of the size it would need to be at (say) 50 Hz or 60 Hz.

In fact, a lot of designs push the limit until it is the MOSFET switching that begins to dominate losses and usually, that's where we stop. It's all about \$V = L\cdot\frac{di}{dt}\$ and implications thereof.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I have understood that when inductor/transformer gets big (in cross section area?) in to accommodate a higher value of current. Thus, a lot of designs increase the switching frequency of the converter, that the current value of through the inductor/transformer is very less, so that the conduction losses are very less. Thus the conduction losses decrease and therefore the efficiency increases. (Switching losses- are still there though)

Comment: It's the magnetization current that you are trying to keep low because this causes core saturation hence, why we make power transformers big (for the same wattage) in 50/60 Hz power systems @Fredrick

Comment: So when the core is magnetized because of the longer duration of current due to lower switching frequency, it goes into saturation. Thus efficiency is reduced due to lower switching frequency?

Comment: @Fredrick it can be really bad if it goes into deep saturation i.e. it blows fuses and can burn copper traces on PCBs. It's the **number one priority** when designing with magnetics. As saturation is entered it's not too bad but, the trouble is you can't really rely on knowing that you are close to entering it. This is why the shrewd engineer tends to use 200 mT as the peak limit. Having said that I have pushed it up to nearly 300 mT on some "special" designs.

Comment: I guess I have selected your answer, I've believed was right. I could upvote since I don't have the privilege yet.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of terms that affect efficiency of switched-mode converters.  At maximum load, these losses are generally dominated by I²R losses in the switches, but there are other considerations as well, especially at lower currents.

Think about a boost converter with a rectifier diode, and an NMOS FET as its main switch.  If the gate of your FET has 2nF capacitance and you charge it up to 5V, that means you have put 10nC of charge on the gate to turn it on.  When you turn it off, that charge is shunted to ground.

If you do this with a period of 1kHz, that's 10nC you're dissipating every 1ms, or 10uA of current you're spending to switch your FET.  At 1MHz switching frequency, this same scenario means you're spending a full 10mA just to charge your gate.  So for a given device, this particular loss term is directly proportional to switching frequency; the more often you toggle your FET, the more current it takes.

An even more relevant loss term is this: If you turn your FET on very slowly, your LX (switching) node spends a long time going from high to low, and that means you have a long time with a large voltage across your main switch while it's conducting.  Because P=I*V, the longer your switching node stays mid-rail instead of close to ground, the longer you're wasting a lot of power on your FET (normally you only have your I*R voltage when it's fully on, which is much smaller).  Because of this term, especially for higher voltages where you have to slew LX further from IN to ground, you benefit from going from "fully off" to "fully on" as quickly as possible.

When they say "The SiC MOSFET's extremely fast switching speed", what they likely mean is that the Gate-Source and Gate-Drain capacitances on these devices is much smaller than they would be for an Si MOSFET.  That means at least two benefits:

1. Less gate charge losses, which allows you to switch at a given frequency more efficiently, and
2. Less IV losses from the FET being stuck in its linear region with LX mid-rail.  Since the FET can fully enhance faster, LX falls faster, and that loss term (also proportional to switching frequency) goes way down at a given fsw.